# Как работает конструкция else else-if?

Tags: c, условия

Допустим, у меня есть такой фрагмент кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 256; i++){
    if (strcmp (dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0 ) break;
    else if (i == (freeCode-1)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Тут я хочу сравнить содержимое двух указателей на `char` и если они равны — выйти из цикла, а если они не равны, и цикл уже прошелся по всему массиву `dictionary`, то перейти к следующей ветке.

Знаю, что вопрос может показаться глупым, но мне же не надо писать:

```
for (int i = 0; i< freeCode; i++){
    if (strcmp (dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0 ) break;
    else if (strcmp (dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0 && i == (freeCode-1)){
        ...
    }
}
```

Чтобы этот цикл отработал так, как мне нужно? В общем, вопрос в том, подставляет ли `else if` предыдущее условие?

Comment: Зачем вручную отслеживать последнюю итерацию цикла, если это происходит автоматически?

Comment: Если срабатывает условие `strcmp (dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0` в первом `if`, то как по-вашему дело может дойти до `else if`?

Comment: Мало того, сработает ещё и `break`, так что даже если бы там было не `else if`, а просто `if` дальше, в него всё-равно управление не попадёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf то есть мне можно обойтись и без else-if. Спасибо

Comment: @mkkik, без отлова   последней итерации действия в цикле не будут происходить много раз, а мне это не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Чтобы этот цикл отработал так, как мне нужно? В общем, вопрос в том,
> подставляет ли `else` `if` предыдущее условие?

Вы работаете в одной итерации, поэтому что для `if`, что для `else` в вашем примере значение `strcmp (dictionary[i]->value, prefix.value) == 0` будет **одинаковым на каждой итерации**.

> Тут я хочу сравнить содержимое двух указателей на char и если они
> равны — выйти из цикла, а если они не равны, и цикл уже прошелся по
> всему массиву dictionary, то перейти к следующей ветке.

Вы перейдете к else только когда сравнить содержимого вернет false, поэтому еще сравнивать не нужно.

```
else if (i == (freeCode-1)){..}
```